# Jovo FrameWork: this.followUpState doesn't do its job like it's supposed to

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot, jovo-framework

I have this intent

```
       'NameIntent': function(name) {

  let speech = 'Hello  ' + name.value + ', nice to meet you! which Radio do you want me to play? ;

      this.followUpState('MakeSureEnterRadioIntentState').ask(speech);
      },
```

which gets triggered with the utterance {name}. Example: User says: SAM

The stateIntent code is as follows:
The PlayRadioIntent get triggered with the utterance {radioName}. Example: User says: Mosaique

```
'MakeSureEnterRadioIntentState': { //TO solve this problem: IN CASE USER SAYS MOSAIQUE AFTER NAMEINTENT ALEXA WILL INTERPRET MOSAIQUE AS A NAME AND WILL REENTER NAMEINTENT

    'PlayRadioIntent': function(channel) {
      this.tell("The radioName is" + channel.value);}
```

The problem I tried to resolve with this state:
ALEXA: Hello Sam nice to meet you! which Radio do you want me to play? ;
USER: Mosaique
//Mosaique is a radio name
ALEXA: Hello Mosaique nice to meet you! which Radio do you want me to play? ;
//ALEXA interprets mosaique as a name instead of a radioName and reenters the NameIntent. I thought using states would be perfect for resolving this confusion. and they SHOULD. But, they aren't and I do not really understand why.
HELP?

Answer (score 1):

The [Jovo Routing](https://www.jovo.tech/docs/routing) works as follows if it is in a state: (1) Look if the intent is found in the state, if not (2) look if "Unhandled" is defined in the state, if not (3) look if the intent can be found outside the state, if not (4) look if "Unhandled" is defined outside the state, if not (5) throw an error.

In your case, "NameIntent" can't be found in the state, so it goes to the global (stateless) "NameIntent". To stay in the state, you can add an "Unhandled" intent that acts as a "catch all" for any intent that can't be found in there.

Take a look at this section to learn more about states and Unhandled: https://www.jovo.tech/blog/p2s5-introduction-to-states/#unhandled-intent

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response. But, I think I wasn't clear enough. I want Alexa to search for PlayRadioIntent inside of the state not the nameIntent. I routed the dialog from the NameIntent to MakeSureEnterRadioIntentState so that when Alexa asks for a radioName and the user answers with a radioName she wouldn't interpret that radioName as a Name and wrongly reenter nameIntent instead of the PlayRadioIntent in the MakeSureEnterRadioIntentState . I hope I have cleared the confusion

Comment: The problem arises from the fact there is a slot {name} for the nameIntent and a slot {RadioName} for the PlayRadioIntent.But, I though the state mechanism sould solve this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't make Alexa listen to just one intent or slot. If Alexa understands "NameIntent" isntead of "PlayRadioIntent", you need to do the matching yourself in the backend. This is where states can be helpful.

Comment: I did use the states. Is the way I implemented them wrong?